# connect Symfony 3 application to an external SQL database in (asterisk server)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, asterisk, symfony

I am developing a VoIP administration platform based on asterisk
and I am not be able to connect to my asterisk server from a web app developed with Symfony 3.

I want to connect to my SQL database existing on asterisk server which is running on virtual machine from my web application and execute some queries like INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT, and DELETE.

Comment: It's not enought that you want, you have to write some code as well.

Comment: @malcolm is right, what have you tried? Do you plan to use 2 database, or just the external database? Is it a MySQL database, or another type? Or is your question really whether this is possible or not?

Comment: thank's very much bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audit your mysql server settings. Try to do the same via commandline. Most probably, your sql server wont be accepting connection from external ip's. It has nothing to do with asterisk.

Comment: thank's Yes  now i am able to connect to an external ip with a simple php code

Comment: but it's so slow !

Comment: The best way to make the transactions faster is to use ARI and connect to ARI using stasis client which should run in the server where your application or mysql server exists.